# git hangs macOS Sierra terminal with no recovery

Tags: git, terminal, macos-sierra

Running git version 2.10.2 (from Homebrew) on macOS Sierra 10.12.1. When I perform a `git pull` it completely hangs my terminal. If I force quit terminal and relaunch then terminal will not start. I've tried the following (from other answers):

1. Change over from using DSA keys to RSA keys (due to deprecation of RSA in the latest OpenSSH)
2. Updated to the latest Homebrew and updated git
3. Tried a different terminal (iTerm)
4. Ensured xcode is up-to-date and reinstalled commandline tools (xcode-select --install)

The fact that it completely hangs Terminal and can't recover makes it very hard to diagnose and it seems to mess with a number of other apps after this, requiring a complete reboot. Any help gratefully received!

Comment: That sounds like your system might be suffering from other issues (like a faulty disk).

Comment: All has been fine until the upgrade to Sierra and other applications seem to run well. Only git pull seems, at the moment, to make things hang.

Comment: When it happens, have you tried running Activity Monitor or Console? Might provide a clue what's happening.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed? I had something like that with some  AVs that intercept ssl connections (they do a man-in-the-middle attack, which was messing up git). Git eventually came back after 2-5 minutes with an error.

Comment: My git hangs when I do either a 'git pull' or 'git add -p'... To make things worse, it only happens sometimes. This makes it impossible to restart the mac too.

Comment: Also to answer the question up above... Activity Monitor goes completely blank when this happens i.e. no processes shown.

Comment: Did more investigation by having GIT_TRACE on for every git command... I figured that this is the line that always hangs: `run_command.c 336
run_command trace: ‘ssh’ ‘<git URL>’ ‘git-upload-pack’ ‘\’ <github repo details>`

Comment: fwiw, i have the exact same issue... iTerm2 hangs and even if i kill it, trying to relaunch it would never come back up.  worse still, launching Mac's terminal app would also never come up.  I was left having to reboot in order to resolve the issue.  in my case it was always hanging whenever i tried to do tab-completion on a git command... so it was related directly to git.  noticing that brew had an update for git, i'm trying to see if upgrading helps.  i'm hoping that this is an issue with a mismatch on the brew version of git with the update to Mac OS X Sierra.  fingers crossed.

Comment: It seems that my SSH theory is wrong - `git add -p` shouldn't have to SSH anything. It is just a local diff command. No idea what is going on. Pretty disappointing - might have to reset my system.

Answer (score 5):

this was most frustating thing i faced in recent times, i used to force restart machine 3-4 times in an hour. but i solved it somehow

```
brew uninstall --force git
```

install git 2.10.1
https://git-scm.com/download/mac

restart terminal window/tab .. check the version of git should be 2.10.1

it is working without any problem for me.